# Downloaded Non-local means filter does not work

Tags: matlab, filter

Below is a downloaded (I have customized it a little bit) algorithm for the Non-local means filter:

```
function [cleared] = Non_Local_Means(I,f,t,h)

[m,n] = size(I);


% Making gaussian kernel
su=1;          %standard deviation of gaussian kernel
sm=0;          % sum of all kernel elements (for normalization)
ks= 2*f+1;     % size of kernel (same as neighborhood window size)
% Initiating kernel
ker = zeros(ks,ks);
for x=1:ks
for y=1:ks
    ab = x-f-1;   %horizontal distance of pixel from center(f+1, f+1)
    cd = y-f-1;   % vertical distance of pixel from center (f+1, f+1)
    ker(x,y) = 100*exp(((ab*ab)+(cd*cd))/(-2*(su*su)));
    sm = sm + ker(x,y);
end
end
kernel = ker ./ f;
kernel = kernel / sm;   % normalization


% Assign a clear output image
cleared = zeros(m,n);


I = padarray(I,[f,f],'symmetric');

% Now we'll calculate ouput for each pixel
for i=1:m
for j=1:n
    im = i+f;   % to compensate for shift due to padarray function
    jn= j+f;
    % neighborhood of concerned pixel (we called it similarity window)
    W1 = I(im-f:im+f , jn-f:jn+f);
    % BOundaries of similarity window for that pixel
    rmin = max(im-t, f+1);
    rmax = min(im+t, m+f);
    smin = max(jn-t, f+1);
    smax = min(jn+t, n+f);
    % Calculate weighted average next
    NL=0;    % same as cleared (i,j) but for simplicity
    Z =0;    % sum of all s(i,j)
    % Run loop through all the pixels in similarity window
    for r=rmin:rmax
        for s=smin:smax
            % neighborhood of pixel 'j' being compared for similarity
            W2 = I(r-f:r+f, s-f:s+f);
            % square of weighted euclidian distances
            d2 = sum(sum(kernel.*(W1-W2).*(W1-W2)));   %LINE 67
            % weight of similarity between both pixels : s(i,j)
            sij = exp(-d2/(h*h));
            % update Z and NL
            Z = Z + sij;
            NL = NL + (sij*I(r,s));
        end
    end
    % normalization of NL
    cleared(i,j) = NL/Z;
end
end
% convert cleared to uint8
cleared = uint8(cleared);

end
```

But it gives me a subsequent mistake:

Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in Non_Local_Means (line 67)
                d2 = sum(sum(kernel.*(W1-W2).*(W1-W2)));

Error in filter_process (line 32)
                eval(['filter_Images.',name_of_cells{i},'(',num2str(m),')','.',column_name{n},'(:,:,',num2str(p),')=Non_Local_Means(filter_Images.',name_of_cells{i},'(',num2str(m),')','.',column_name{n},'(:,:,',num2str(p),'),f,t,h);'])

Error in untitled>pushbutton13_Callback (line 1157)
handles.filtered_Images = filter_process(Images, f, t, h);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton13_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

How can I solve this problem (LINE 67)?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cool! So you got someone else’s code and share it openly here, without attribution, in blatant disregard for copyright laws?

Comment: If the original code you downloaded shows this issue, take it up with the author of the code. If it is your modification, try to remove parts of the code that don’t contribute to the error, so as to make a smallest possible bit of code that has the error. Then post that here. It’s called a [mcve], and makes it possible for people to point out your problem without wasting time reading through pages of irrelevant code.

Comment: At first, there are only relevant parts.
At second, I asked authors a few times, never got an answer.
At third, it's CUSTOMIZED, so it's not exactly the same (it is written in the beginning).

Comment: So if I take your code and change it a bit it no longer is your code? That is not how copyright works. You need to attribute. You also need to read the link I posted, this example is not minimal, and not complete. The error message you posted references code I don’t see in the post. If you want a total stranger to help you debug your code, the least you can do is make it easier.

Comment: As was pointed out before, no one will be able to help you with your problem under the given circumstances. However, besides the copyright question, I cannot understand how you can modify a code and not beeing able to debug it. Why dont you figure out yourself what exactly happens in line 67 that it throws an error. (Breakpoints???) Once you understand that, and you still dont know what to do, you should make your question more specific!!!